# Communication between service and fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a PageView with multiple fragments and a bind Service. I connect to the service from each fragment the following way:

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
            IBinder service) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        ...
    }
};
```

The problem is: since it takes a short interval to connect to the service each time the PageView is scrolled, there's a slight lag.

Ideally I would like to bind the Activity to the service and pass the service reference to the fragments.

How can I access the Service reference from fragment through activity? Thank you.

Comment: check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40750712/how-to-access-service-functions-from-fragment-which-is-bound-to-parent-activity